# Analogue of van der Corput sequence for prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-approximation, analytic-number-theory

A van der Corput sequence is a low-discrepancy sequence over the unit interval first published in 1935 by the Dutch mathematician J. G. van der Corput. It is constructed by placing a decimal point and writing the base $n$ representation of the sequence of natural numbers in the reverse order. [Read more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_sequence).

This question is motivated by curiosity to study the analogue of van der Corput sequence for prime numbers. Consider the sequence $v_p$ formed by placing a decimal point and writing the digits of the sequence of prime numbers $p$ in the reverse order (in base 10). The first few terms of this sequence are

$$
0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.11, 0.31, 0.71, 0.91, 0.32, 0.92, \ldots
$$

Clearly $v_p$ is not equidistributed in the unit interval and therefore it is not a low discrepancy sequence. I am curious to know if $v_p$ has anything interesting property in it.

Q1. What is the mean value of the sequence $v_p$? In other words does the following limit exist?

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{p \le x}v_p.
$$

**Edit** (*Adding Timothy's guess as a question*)

Q2. What would be the mean value of base $b$?

Q3. **Edit** (*@ one more variation for this problem*)

Find a closed form representation of

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{p\le x}f(v_p)
$$

where $f$ is any function Riemann integrable in $(0,1)$?

Considering the analogy with the equidistribution theorem, I think this should be possible.

Comment: Should be 0.55. Truncate to the first n digits to get an answer within $10^{-n}$. Then use the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions to show that all sequences of n digits with the first odd appear with equal probability (with error going to 0 as $x \rightarrow \infty$). Now let $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: First digit odd and not equal 5, you mean (though as it happens this doesn't change the average).  Your comment appeared while I was writing much the same thing as an answer...

Comment: I think we can do this without the prime number theorem since the mean for $v_{2n+1}$ is 0.55. Hence in general any sequence $v_{a_n}$ the mean should depend only the set of different possible last (unit's) digit that $a_n$ can take.

Comment: well, $\varphi(b)$ is even for $b>2$, and $(-1,b)=1$, so you pair off $r+0.5$ with $b-r+0.5$ when you average.

Comment: wonder what other variations can be invented for this question?

Comment: Here is one variation motivated by the equidistribution theorem. Find a closed form of $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}\sum_{p\le x}f(v_p)$. 


Comment: Oops, yes, I second Noam Elkies's correction!

Comment: Since $\lbrace v_p \rbrace$ is equidistributed on $\Pi_b$, the asymptotic average of $f(v_p)$ should just be the average of $f$ over $\Pi_b$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While $\lbrace v_p \rbrace$ is clearly not equidistributed in $(0,1)$, it *is* equidistributed in
$$
\Pi_{10} := [.1,.2) \cup [.3,.4) \cup [.7,.8) \cup [.9,1)
$$
by the prime number theorem (PNT) for arithmetic progressions modulo powers of $10$.  In particular, the average tends to $0.55$, the average of the midpoints $0.15$, $0.35$, $0.75$, and $0.95$ of these four intervals.

[I see that Frank Thorne wrote much the same thing in a comment as I was editing this...]

[added in reply to further inquiries:] Replacing $10$ by an arbitrary base $b>1$, we likewise use the PNT for arithmetic progressions (APs) modulo powers of $b$ to show that the sequence is equidistributed in
$$
\Pi_b := \lbrace x \in [0,1) : \gcd(\lfloor bx \rfloor, b) = 1 \rbrace.
$$
(I made the intervals half-open in $\Pi_{10}$ for consistency with this definition, though it doesn't change the distribution.)  That's a union of $\varphi(b)$ intervals of length $1/b$ whose set of left endpoints is symmetric about $1/2$, so the average is $1/2 + 1/(2b) = (b+1)/2b$ as Timothy Foo surmised.

On further thought, not only does equidistribution in $\Pi_b$ follow from the PNT for APs modulo every power of $b$, but the two statements are readily seen to be equivalent.

Comment: And I guess that in base $b$, the mean would be $(b+1)/2b$.